# Wrong select query generated with Entity Framework (mysterious extra column)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm playing around trying to get a simple MVC website working. In it I am using a database and Entity Framework to communicate with it (as I have been doing for months on other projects).

Everything has been going fine up until I tried to retrieve from a specific table in my database. If I query that, the select that EF generates mysteriously contains a column that does not exists in that table (or any table in that database). This of course throws an exception complaining about the column not existing:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'PerformerFolder_Id'.

I've created a `UnitOfWork` object that uses the repository pattern to retrieve the data, and to make it as simple as possible, I exposed the `DataContext` so I could manually query that for testing:

```
var test = loUnitOfWork.Context.Set<DAL.File>();
```

The `DAL.File` is a class generated by the POCO generator:

```
public partial class File : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FilePerformer> FilePerformerCollection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileProperty> FilePropertyCollection { get; set; }

    public File()
    {
        FilePerformerCollection = new List<FilePerformer>();
        FilePropertyCollection = new List<FileProperty>();
        InitializePartial();
    }
    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

I do have a `PerformerFolder` that has an `Id` column as the primary key, but that is in no way connected to the file table.

If I enable debug logging on the `DataContext` I see that it runs the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[FilePath] AS [FilePath], 
    [Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
    [Extent1].[PerformerFolder_Id] AS [PerformerFolder_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[File] AS [Extent1]
```

I've tried searching all file for "PerformerFolder" and other than the logical places (in the PerformerFolder class) it did not turn up anything. It seems to be generated based on something, but I just can't figure out what or where.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a partial class for File entity?

Comment: It is a partial class, but other than the generated class none exist.

Comment: Does PerformerFolder have other partial class ?

Comment: It does have a file for it, but it is empty as of yet. So effectively not.

Comment: do `PerformerFolder` have a list of `File`s?

Comment: Nope, the only relations are 2 Foreign Keys referencing this table's PK: "FileProperties to File" "PerformerFile" to File"

Comment: I think you have to show us the datamodels (not just file) or try to create a short self contained compilable example. It's just guesses from here on.

Comment: I have to stand corrected. The `PerformerFolder` partial class file was not in fact empty. It contains a function that does return a list of `File`s. Adding `[NotMapped]` to that fixed it. Boy did I give myself some extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching all code files for `PerformerFolder` without the 'id'
EF adds that to navigation properties on it's own.

as @Giorgi mentioned, it must be a partial class somewhere, or maybe a left over from a previous build ?

Comment: This should be a comment, really. But see *I've tried searching all file for "PerformerFolder"* and the partial class question is also clear now.

Comment: That's what I did. And all the locations I see are expected and not related to File. In the DataContext class (declared both the interface and the class itself, and in the CreateModel and OnModelCreating functions) and in the generated Performer and PerformerFolder classes.

I also tried cleaning my solution and rebuilding, but this is a new project, so there isn't really anything left over

Comment: In the comments on my question I replied that putting `[NotMapped]` above a getter in the `PerformerFolder` partial class fixed it. I was trying to create a stripped down project to be able to share here and saw that removing that partial class, which I was sure of was empty, fixed the problem.